# Do i need to be synchronized to blockchain when creating DAG for mining on pool?

Tags: dag

When mining for pool, the DAG has to be created. Before starting mining and DAG creation do i need to be synced to blockchain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You don't have to sync to the blockchain if you are mining on a pool.

The pool will provide your miner with the appropriate information for your miner to generate the DAG file required for it's mining computation.

### Details

The pool will be running an Ethereum node, normally `geth` (see https://www.ethernodes.org/network/1).

Your miner will call the [eth_getWork](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getwork) RPC API from the pool proxy address. The pool's proxy will pass on this request to the pool's Ethereum node software and the node software will pass the results back to your miner via the pool's proxy.

The results of the `eth_gethWork` APi call sent back to your miner will contain the information required for your miner to generate the appropriate DAG file:

From the documentation linked above, here are the results from `eth_getWork`:

- DATA, 32 Bytes - current block header pow-hash
- DATA, 32 Bytes - **the seed hash used for the DAG**.
- DATA, 32 Bytes - the boundary condition ("target"), 2^256 / difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it depends on the mining software but with ethminer using a pool you don't have to sync at all. The pool does the sync and send you the data to compute. You only have to prepare it and share it on your GPUs.